# Sort list in C# to merge the items of each list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list of emails grouped by hostname. I need to join these emails in an interleaved way and then send them.

```
public List<string> ReturnOrder()
{ 
    List<string> listMerge = new List<string>();
    List<List<string>> listEmail = new List<List<string>>();
    listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@yahoo.com", "email02@yahoo.com", "email03@yahoo.com" });            
    listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@gmail.com", "email02@gmail.com" });
    listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@outlook.com", "email02@outlook.com", "email03@outlook.com", "email04@outlook.com"});
    return listMerge;
}
```

```
//Order:
email01@yahoo.com
email01@gmail.com
email01@outlook.com
email02@yahoo.com
email02@gmail.com
email02@outlook.com
email03@yahoo.com
email03@outlook.com
email04@outlook.com
```

I need to get the following result, I made several unsuccessful attempts

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll get much better answers if you share the attempts you've made, and the specific errors or problems you encountered with those attempts.

Comment: How come email01@yahoo.com comes before email01@gmail.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic implementation would be something like this:

```
        List<string> listMerge = new List<string>();
        List<List<string>> listEmail = new List<List<string>>();
        listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@yahoo.com", "email02@yahoo.com", "email03@yahoo.com" });
        listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@gmail.com", "email02@gmail.com" });
        listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@outlook.com", "email02@outlook.com", "email03@outlook.com", "email04@outlook.com" });

        for(int i =0; i < listEmail.Select(x => x.Count).Max(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < listEmail.Count; j++)
            {
                if (listEmail[j].Count <= i)
                    continue;

                listMerge.Add(listEmail[j][i]);
            }
        }
```

Each time the outer loop ends, one item from all lists in consumed. So, the outer loop runs for the number of iterations equal to longest list.

Inner loop loops through each list and picks one item (if one exists for the specified index.)

This can probably be made more efficient, but for your purposes, this much should be sufficient.

Comment: This suspiciously feels like an interview question! :)

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to sort your list with the complex List<List> type?

If you want to sort a more complex list, like a more dimensional one, and return just the sorted elements as a simple list, you should always start to flatten your list to a one dimensional list.

```
public static List<string> FlattenComplexList(List<List<string>> complexList)
{
    List<string> flattenList = new();

    complexList.ForEach(entry => flattenList.AddRange(entry));

    return flattenList;
}
```

After you have flatten your list, you can just use the sort function of c# to sort your one dimensional array.

Comment: This example list is a list that I cannot change. I need to order the elements so that I can then send an email to each type of host in this order: (yahoo1, gmail1, outlook1, yahoo2, gmail2, outlook2...) but not all of them will be the same size.

Comment: Do you mean the example list of your question, which you cannot change?

And which attempts did you already try?

Comment: The last attempt I created a new list of type List<EmailDTO> with a field with the email and a string index. I tried the following sequence for the first list (1,2,3,4...) second list (11,22,33,44) and third list or more if you have (111,222,333,444) then at the end I would sort it. But it didn't work because it orders 1,10,100.. then it would come 11, 111.

Answer (score 1):

you can do select many from complex list and then to orderby

```html
    List<string> listMerge = new List<string>();
    List<List<string>> listEmail = new List<List<string>>();
    listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@yahoo.com", "email02@yahoo.com", "email03@yahoo.com" });            
    listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@gmail.com", "email02@gmail.com" });
    listEmail.Add(new List<string> { "email01@outlook.com", "email02@outlook.com", "email03@outlook.com", "email04@outlook.com"});
        listMerge=listEmail.SelectMany(i=>{
        return i;
        }).OrderBy(o=>{
            return o;
        }).ToList();
   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listMerge));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a List of Lists (or more generally, an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerables`), you can flatten them using the LINQ method `SelectMany()`:

```cs
List<string> listMerge = listEmail.SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
// "email01@yahoo.com", "email02@yahoo.com", "email03@yahoo.com", "email01@gmail.com", "email02@gmail.com", "email01@outlook.com", "email02@outlook.com", "email03@outlook.com", "email04@outlook.com"
```

Unfortunately, this will simply append the lists back-to-back, it will not interleave them as you requested.

---

Your unique requirement can be solved with a little cleverness by finding the largest list, implementing your own zip with null placeholders, and then flattening the result. A for loop would be clearest, but here's a quick stab using only LINQ for fun:

```cs
int longestList = listEmail.Max(list => list.Count);
List<string> listMerge = Enumerable.Range(0, longestList)
    .Select(i => listEmail.Select(list => list.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault()))
    .SelectMany(l => l)
    .Where(email => email != null)
    .ToList();
```

---

For your future information, there is another LINQ method that can be used to interleave two IEnumerables of the same length called `Zip()`, but this is not useful today because you have 3 lists, and they are of a different lengths.

---

**Final Solution:**

```cs
List<List<string>> listEmail = new List<List<string>>();
listEmail.Add(new List<string>{"email01@yahoo.com", "email02@yahoo.com", "email03@yahoo.com"});
listEmail.Add(new List<string>{"email01@gmail.com", "email02@gmail.com"});
listEmail.Add(new List<string>{"email01@outlook.com", "email02@outlook.com", "email03@outlook.com", "email04@outlook.com"});
int longestList = listEmail.Max(list => list.Count);
List<string> listMerge = Enumerable.Range(0, longestList)
    .Select(i => listEmail.Select(list => list.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault()))
    .SelectMany(l => l).Where(email => email != null).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", listMerge));
```

You can test this out here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hHpf9G

[image]

Output: `email01@yahoo.com, email01@gmail.com, email01@outlook.com, email02@yahoo.com, email02@gmail.com, email02@outlook.com, email03@yahoo.com, email03@outlook.com, email04@outlook.com`

Answer (score 0):

A crude method using Linq would be:

```
var sorted = listEmail.SelectMany( (el, io) => el.Select((e,ii) => new {inner=ii, outer=io, email=e}))
                      .OrderBy(x => x.inner)
                      .ThenBy(x => x.outer)
                      .Select(x => x.email);
```

Translation: Flatten the list of lists, grabbing the index of the item in each list and the index of the list. Then order first by the index of the item, then by the index of the list.

But, that's not terribly intuitive. I would prefer the explicit loop that R J suggests (and it will be faster since you don't have to "sort" the data when you're accessing the lists in order)